# Existe alguma API para trabalhar com QR code?

Tags: android-studio, qrcode

Preciso ler um *QR code* e fazer check-in em um aplicativo que estou desenvolvendo para Android. Existe alguma API pronta para trabalhar com *QR code*?

Comment: Que eu conheça existe o **zxing** que parece ser o mais conhecido. O projeto é https://github.com/zxing/zxing/

Answer (score 2):

Opa, você não precisa de uma API para trabalhar com QR Code. Existem libs para isso, e a mais famosa é a que o Wakim respondeu, zxing - https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Existem outras também: barcodescanner - https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner

android-quick-response-code (desatualizada) - https://github.com/phishman3579/android-quick-response-code